# Convert pair of two vectors to a map of corresponding elements

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am trying to convert `std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>` to `std::map<int, double>`.

For example:

```
// I have this:
std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>> temp =
                            {{2, 3, 4}, {4.3, 5.1, 6.4}};
// My goal is this:
std::map<int, double> goal = {{2, 4.3}, {3, 5.1}, {4, 6.4}};
```

I can achieve this with the following function. However, I feel like there must be a better way to do this. If so what is it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<int> vec_i;
typedef std::vector<double> vec_d;

std::map<int, double> pair_to_map(std::pair<vec_i, vec_d> my_pair)
{
    std::map<int, double> my_map;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < my_pair.first.size(); ++i)
    {
        my_map[my_pair.first[i]] = my_pair.second[i];
    }
    return my_map;
}

int main()
{

    std::pair<vec_i, vec_d> temp = {{2, 3, 4}, {4.3, 5.1, 6.4}};

    std::map<int, double> new_map = pair_to_map(temp);

    for (auto it = new_map.begin(); it != new_map.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm currently trying `boost::zip_iterator`, but there seems to be an incompatibility between the involved boost types (like `boost::tuple`) and the StdLib types (like `std::pair`). It is possible to rewrite a zip-iterator for StdLib types to break this down to `return {make_zip_iterator(begin(p.first), begin(p.second)), make_zip_iterator(end(p.first), end(p.second))};` (The zip iterator will return a pair/tuple that can be used to construct the value type of the map to be returned.)

Comment: @dyp Jonathan Wakely [has a really nice wrapper for `zip_iterator`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10457201/2756719).

Comment: @T.C. The fundamental problem seems to be that a `tuple` is not convertible to a `pair`. `zip_iterator` (necessarily) operators with `tuple`s, whereas `map` only deals with `pair`s (its value type).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way:

```
std::transform(std::begin(temp.first), std::end(temp.first)
             , std::begin(temp.second)
             , std::inserter(new_map, std::begin(new_map))
             , [] (int i, double d) { return std::make_pair(i, d); });
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d982cb8753fb1558)

or even without a lambda:

```
std::transform(std::begin(temp.first), std::end(temp.first)
             , std::begin(temp.second)
             , std::inserter(new_map, std::begin(new_map))
             , &std::make_pair<int&, double&>);
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b15dd23fbca1c86)

or in a C++03 fashion:

```
std::transform(temp.first.begin(), temp.first.end()
             , temp.second.begin()
             , std::inserter(new_map, new_map.begin())
             , &std::make_pair<int, double>);
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cf97f10b463d176)

Output:

```
2 : 4.3
3 : 5.1
4 : 6.4
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Boost's range algorithm extensions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/new/for_each.html):

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/for_each.hpp>

boost::for_each(temp.first, temp.second, [&](int i, double d) { new_map[i] = d; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36a1887e7ff19af3).

This also has the benefit of being safe even if the length of the two vectors are different.